# 'Malformed class name' error when trying to concatenate arrays of zeros to an existing row that's an array[array[int]]

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to create arrays of zeros and then append them to all the rows in my dataframe using a udf as per:

```
    val padding_udf = udf((input: Array[Array[Int]]) => {
val max_length = 30
val diff = (max_length - input.length)
println(input.length)
val num = 5
val padding = Array.ofDim[Int](diff,num)
//if ((input.size - max_length) != 0) 
input++padding
})
```

The rows in the column I'm trying to append to consist of arrays[arrays[int]] (they appear as wrapped arrays when I show the dataframe).

When I try to apply this udf to my dataframe I get the following error: 'Malformed class name'

```
at java.lang.Class.getSimpleBinaryName(Class.java:1450)
at java.lang.Class.getSimpleName(Class.java:1309)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.udfErrorMessage$lzycompute(ScalaUDF.scala:1065)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.udfErrorMessage(ScalaUDF.scala:1064)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:231)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:225)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -13